# Debug blazor wasm using visual studio container tools

Tags: visual-studio, docker, blazor-client-side

I've been using blazor wasm (hosted by aspnet core) in some of my projects for a while now. Since dotnet core I prefer to run my apps in containers. Visual studio has container and orchestration support, I've added this to my blazor solution and it works fine in release configuration.

However when I try to use the debug configuration (aka `container fast mode`) I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.BlazorHostingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseClientSideBlazorFiles(IApplicationBuilder app, String clientAssemblyFilePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.BlazorHostingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseClientSideBlazorFiles[TClientApp](IApplicationBuilder app)
   at BlazorWasmOnDocker.Server.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in D:\OpenSource\aspnetcore-apis\BlazorWasmOnDocker\BlazorWasmOnDocker\Server\Startup.cs:line 36
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
```

I've seen multiple github issues being created for this e.g. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9704#issuecomment-544272050 but since blazor wasm isn't out of beta yet, these issues haven't been resolved.

How can I run blazor wasm hosted by asp as a container in fast mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To isolate this problem I've created a blazor wasm app that's hosted in ASP.net core by using the latest visual studio template (blazor 3.1 preview 4) and the lastest visual studio 2019 preview.

After schaffolding a solution I added docker support and orchestration support in visual studio. This got me a setup that'll work when ran in release mode.

To fix debug mode/container fast mode I read up on how visual studio runs containers in debug and release mode. See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses the generated Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

In a nutshell: when using release mode visual studio builds your dockerfile and thus your app is created build **and publishes** in the container itself which will create an app that contains your asp server and blazor client in `/app`.

When using debug mode visual studio will only run the first stage of your dockerfile and then mount your 'server' project into the container. It then builds your 'server' project on your machine (this is faster then building it in the container), since the server project is mounted the compiled results are also in the container. Visual studio then starts a remote debugging session in the container which starts your app.

The debug setup differs from the release setup in that there's no publish when debugging, and thus the blazor client isn't copied into your asp server app but is linked with a generated blazor config file (it's in your bin dir, mine is named `BlazorWasmOnDocker.Client.blazor.config`).

Since the build ran outside of the container, the generated blazor.config also created links that only work outside of the container. For my setup it was something like:

`D:\Software\repos\aspnetcore-apis\BlazorWasmOnDocker\BlazorWasmOnDocker\Client\BlazorWasmOnDocker.Client.csproj`

And here in lies the problem, or actually 2 problems:

1. The client project isn't mounted in the container
2. The configured location of the blazor project is incorrect for
   running in a container

Fixing the first problem can be done by creating a debug docker-compose.yml file (call it `docker-compose.vs.debug.yml` so visual studio will use it when debugging) which adds a mount to the client project:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  blazorwasmondocker.server:
    volumes:
      - ./BlazorWasmOnDocker/Client:/Client
```

Fixing the second problem can be done by correcting the paths to the client project in the generated blazor config after a debug build. I did so in the program.cs you could also do it in the container startup or post build hook.

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            const string blazorConfigPath = @"/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/BlazorWasmOnDocker.Client.blazor.config";
            var blazorConfig = File.ReadAllText(blazorConfigPath);
            blazorConfig = Regex.Replace(blazorConfig, @"[a-zA-Z]:\\.+?\\Client\\", "/Client/")
                .Replace('\\', '/');
            File.WriteAllText(blazorConfigPath, blazorConfig);
#endif

            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
```

As a reference I've pushed a demo project to github and put the fix in 1 commit: https://github.com/Rora/aspnetcore-apis/commit/7ef4682d1466bd94faaba9adafac2cb0f6f59723

Answer (score 0):

*Edit2: Fixed in vs 17.8 preview 3 (or dotnet 8 rc2)*

*Edit: The bug has been found. It is in incorrect use of string.startswith and folders in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.PathUtilities.TryGetContainerPath..*

Temporary workaround is therefore very simple:

Rename the folder your projects are in, so the server and client does not share the same substring.

e.g.
`c:\solution\project` and `c:\solution\project.Client`

rename `c:\solution\project` to `c:\solution\bugproject`

and update the .sln file to use the right folder.

**old solution:**

This is a very annoying problem, and @Rob has the right solution.

It happens because in docker fast build mode, the build generate xxx.staticwebassets.runtime.json that contains paths with the HOST paths to the source code.

Here is a more complete fixer class:

```
//in docker fast build mode it makes a staticwebassets.runtime.json that contains path from the HOST, we need to convert that to the docker
partial class FixStaticWebAssetsFileForDocker
{
   [GeneratedRegex("(?<basepath>[a-zA-Z]:\\\\.+?\\\\)(?:MainProject|BlazorProject|BlazorProject2)\\\\", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)]
   private static partial Regex Basepath();
   [GeneratedRegex("(?<basepath>[a-zA-Z]:\\\\.+?\\\\)\\.nuget\\\\", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)]
   private static partial Regex NugetBasePath();

   public static void FixIt()
   {
      //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228315/debug-blazor-wasm-using-visual-studio-container-tools
      //enumerate all of the "*.staticwebassets.runtime.json" in the folder of the current assembly
      var directoryOfAssembly = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location)!;
      foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryOfAssembly, "*.staticwebassets.runtime.json"))
      {
         var json        = File.ReadAllText(file);
         //detect the basepath
         var group   = Basepath().Match(json).Groups["basepath"];
         //means that visual studio compiled it correctly, or we previously replaced it properly
         if (!group.Success) return;
         var basePath = group.Value;
         Console.WriteLine($"Detected basepath {basePath}");
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))   FixBasePath(ref json, basePath, "MainProject\\\\", "/app/");
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) FixBasePath(ref json, basePath, "MainProject\\\\", "c:\\\\inetpub\\\\wwwroot\\\\");

         //to match the mapping in the docker compose file to compensate for docker SDK not supporting blazor apps
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))   FixBasePath(ref json, basePath, "BlazorProject\\\\", "/BlazorProject/");
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) FixBasePath(ref json, basePath, "BlazorProject\\\\", "c:\\\\BlazorProject\\\\");

         //to match the mapping in the docker compose file to compensate for docker SDK not supporting blazor apps
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))   FixBasePath(ref json, basePath, "BlazorProject2\\\\", "/BlazorProject2/");
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) FixBasePath(ref json, basePath, "BlazorProject2\\\\", "c:\\\\BlazorProject2\\\\");

         var nugetbasePath = NugetBasePath().Match(json).Groups["basepath"].Value ?? throw new NullReferenceException("nugetbasePath");
         Console.WriteLine($"Detected nugetbasePath {nugetbasePath}");
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))   FixBasePath(ref json, nugetbasePath, "", "/root/");
         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) FixBasePath(ref json, nugetbasePath, "", "c:\\\\.nuget\\\\");

         if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)) json = json.Replace("\\\\", "/");

         File.WriteAllText(file, json);
         static void FixBasePath(ref string json, string basePath, string extra, string newbasePath) => json = json.Replace(basePath + extra, newbasePath);
      }
   }
}
#endif
```

To use put this as the very first code in program.cs

```
   var isDocker = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER"));

#if DEBUG
   if (isDocker) FixStaticWebAssetsFileForDocker.FixIt();
#endif
```

and in your docker-compose.yml (for linux) file:

```
services:
  blabla:
    volumes:
      #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228315/debug-blazor-wasm-using-visual-studio-container-tools
      - .\BlazorProject:/BlazorProject
      - .\BlazorProject2:/BlazorProject2
```

and in your docker-compose.yml (for windows) file:

```
services:
  blabla:
    volumes:
      #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228315/debug-blazor-wasm-using-visual-studio-container-tools
      - .\BlazorProject:c:\BlazorProject
      - .\BlazorProject2:c:\BlazorProject2
```

Comment: My staticwebassets.runtime.json files don't have anything like .nuget so NugetBasePath doesn't recognize anything and empty string returned. I run the project but I cannot debug my blazor wasm project. This is my project https://github.com/mlemniscate/TestForDockerCompose

Comment: @Cine The shared substring issue has been fixed in VS 2022 17.8 Preview 3: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Comment: @MiladAbdi Your test project works in 17.7 if you remove FixStaticWebAssetsFileForDocker